# Is it possible to track cookies etc on an Apple Device i.e. Iphone, Ipad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, mobile

I run an affiliate site (voucher code) and I am in the process of looking at developing an IOS app that will potentially display the vouchers etc on the app. Does anyone know if affiliate tracking links run as they are intended when opening a link on an Iphone device. Also can the link open the main Safari app or does the browsing have to be within the voucher app?

So an example being you click the link, it refers you to the affiliate network. The network stores a cookie on the device and you are directed to the site. Do cookies store as intended on a mobile device?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at NSHTTPCookieStorage, it may help you.

`NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];

NSArray *cookies = [storage cookiesForURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://google.com/"]];`